# NonFactors.Grid.Mvc6 click not fires

Tags: asp.net-core, grid

I am attempting to implement paging in my simple ASP.NET Core 2.2 application. 
I executed the command `Install-Package NonFactors.Grid.Mvc6` to install the package and followed all the installation steps described in [this](http://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/Home/Installation) page. 
I can see the data displayed in grid but when I click to show the next records the paging in not moving to show the other records. 
I am missing any scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the test followed the tutorial that you provided , but it worked well. Make sure your styles and scripts are saved as follows:

[image]

Then include grid styling sheet and grid scripts to _Layout.cshtml like below:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link href="~/Content/MvcGrid/mvc-grid.css" rel="stylesheet">
</environment>

 <environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/MvcGrid/mvc-grid.js"></script>
    <script>
        [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('mvc-grid'), function (element) {
                         new MvcGrid(element);
                     });
    </script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
```