# MVC6 Grid not displaying anything

Tags: grid, asp.net-core-mvc

After spending ages doing a .NET Core web application I have just made the horrific discovery that there is no WebGrid!

I cannot get a commercial one so I found MVC6 grid

I followed all the instructions [here](https://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/installation)

I have data, but the grid is not rendered at all

There are no errors in the console

Has anyone encountered this or can suggest a better free grid?

Paul

Answer (score 1):

After install the library , please confirm that the styles and scripts files are inside `wwwroot` folder where asp.net core [static files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1) milldeware works . Also make sure you have correctly  reference them in your `_Layout.cshtml` , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55807746/5751404) is a relevant thread .

Please click [here](https://github.com/NonFactors/AspNetCore.Grid.Web) for Official Asp.net Core MVC6.Grid code sample.